# Get running / walking pace in steps per minute using React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I'm developing an app in which i'll play music which is synced your current walking or running pace. In order to do so i have tried using a pedometer input from expo, however this isn't working too great. Input of the pedometer is delayed and is therefore hard to fix. Is there a "better" way to get pedometer inputs in react native more reliably? Otherwise i could opt for trying to guess a walking / running pace by deeming how fast the user is travelling with google maps or similar.

How would you approach my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would drop expo. With expo you will be limited in the capabilities of your app, meaning you won't be able to add 3rd party native libraries to your app. These are what you are looking for to get the data you want. A quick google search found this, and I guarantee there are many other similar packages if this doesn't quite fit your needs: https://github.com/mathieudutour/react-native-pedometer

Once you drop expo, a world of possibilities will open up to you, but if you are unable to drop expo ... Not being an expo expert, I'm not sure what can be done to get better data. Depending on what you have made so far, dropping expo may be a difficult experience. Either way, good luck.